# Bridged Adapter internet doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet, virtualbox-networking

I have 3 VM that uses Bridged Adapter. The internet was working fine in all of them but suddenly it doesn't even connect. I'm not sure of the problem, but could it be because of resetting my router? I did it recently.

This is the result of running this command, I guess there have to be eth0 in it?

```
/etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

ifconfig command:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:70:02:e6  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe70:2e6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:48714 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6909091 (6.9 MB)  TX bytes:1333637 (1.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5383 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5383 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1206653 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:1206653 (1.2 MB)
```

Also, the routing table is completely empty.

Comment: Please include the output of `ifconfig`

Comment: @CharlesGreen I edited the post and added it

Comment: What type of VM hypervisor are you using?

Comment: @CharlesGreen Virtual Box

Comment: I use VMWare, but I know that in the dialog that I use to set the network to bridged, I can also power down and disconnect the lan 'cards' - have you checked to ensure the devices are enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && ifup -v eth0
```

Comment: It gives me this after running the command 

`ifdown: interface eth0 not configured`
`ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0` @Adzo